# Clicking component inside renderHeader prop for MUI Data Grid Pro changes the sortModel

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, mui-x

I'm using [Material UI DataGridPro](https://mui.com/components/data-grid/#commercial-version) component to build a React Js app.

I want to create a custom filtering.

The red box in the image below is an `IconButton` for the filtering view and the blue box is for the column showing/hiding view.

[image]

I want to change the behavior of the custom filtering view.

If the filter icon is clicked, then the `DataGridPro` header will show some `Select` and `TextField` components as the filter fields like this image below.

[image]

If we click one of the `Select` and `TextField` components, the `Data Grid Pro` component will trigger the `onSortModelChange` prop to change the `sortModel` value like this image below.

[image]

So now the `Data Grid Pro` component is sorted based on the column.

**Here is the conditions I want:**
if we click one of the `Select` and `TextField` components inside the `Data Grid Pro` header, the `Data Grid Pro` will not trigger the `onSortModelChange` prop which means that the `sortModel` value is not changed

Here is the playground: https://codesandbox.io/s/stackoverflow-mui-data-grid-render-header-xmwf0?file=/src/App.js

I have tried to add `sortable: false` for every column but it will not show the arrow icon inside the `Data Grid Pro` header and prevent the column to be sorted. That's not what I want.

I also have added `sortModel` and `onSortModelChange` props for the `Data Grid Pro` component to control the `sortModel` value but it hasn't worked.

**So, what's the solution for this case?**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The MUI X team told me from the Github issue here https://github.com/mui/mui-x/issues/3655#issuecomment-1015263995 that the solution is very simple.

Just add `event.stopPropagation()` for the `onClick` prop of each `TextField` and `Select` component.

```js
onClick={(event) => event.stopPropagation()}
```